# Unable to create usergroup: Error : Node no longer exists

Tags: alfresco

I unable to create user groups from both ui and javascript console.

```
var newGroup = people.getGroup("GROUP_"+groupName);
logger.log(newGroup);
```

gives log :Node no longer exists: workspace://SpacesStore/

Error log when trying to create manually

```
    2018-12-23 23:51:48,650 ERROR [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-bio-10.130.81.13-4080-exec-10662] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 11230029 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 1123121176 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/groups/parent.get.js': Failed invocation: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public abstract java.util.List org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeService.getParentAssocs(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,org.alfresco.service.namespace.QNamePattern,org.alfresco.service.namespace.QNamePattern) throws org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.InvalidNodeRefException; target is of class [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16]
    org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 11230029 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 1123121176 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/groups/parent.get.js': Failed invocation: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public abstract java.util.List org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeService.getParentAssocs(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,org.alfresco.service.namespace.QNamePattern,org.alfresco.service.namespace.QNamePattern) throws org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.InvalidNodeRefException; target is of class [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16]
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:484)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:457)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:559)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:628)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:400)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:281)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a group then use the following

```
var newGroup = people.createGroup(groupName);
```

Regards,
Kintu